Can't Install APKs based on arm64 on android studio emulator
This is the error I get:
The APK failed to install. Error: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113
I am:

installing an external APK of an app downloaded from apkpure.com I have no ability to adjust the apk itself

I tried to install ARM on android studio. When I tried to open it in android emulator, it gave me an error


I just want to open this APK on android studio emulator. Is it impossible now?
Much thanks

What emulator image do you use? Emulator images are x86_64 by default, only some (AFAIR the images marked as "Google") have a built-in emulation that also allows to run arm[64] apps.

This error “INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS” suggests that the APK you wish to install has a different segment architecture (ABI) than that of the emulator. An ABIs or Application Binary Interfaces is used to determine the processor architecture of the apk files. The most popular ones are:
- ‘armeabi-v7a’ (32-bit ARM)
- ‘arm64-v8a’ (64-bit ARM)
- ‘x86’ (Intel)
- ‘x86_64’ (Intel 64-bit)
Use the steps below to address this error:
1. Examine APK’s Architecture: One way of examining the architecture (s) supported by the APK would be by examining the file (for example, the APK Analyzer application in Android Studio or an APK decompiler). You want to ensure that the APK supports an ABI compatible with the emulator.
2.Change the Emulator’s Architecture:

Launch Android Studio, and on the top bar click on AVD Manager.

Locate the AVD (Android Virtual Device) that you are using, and click on it.

First check, if you need to change the CPU/ABI setting, it should conform to the engine architecture used in the APK. For example, if the APK is arm64-v8a, make sure the emulator is configured to the same architecture.

If the APK is in favor of ‘armeabi-v7a’, then try ARM based emulator (not in x85 or x86_64).



Try a Different Emulator: In case you are using an emulator that does not match the APK, you may have to download or define a new AVD with the appropriate architecture. It is usually the case that ARM emulators are slower in performance but should support more APKs.

Check if the Emulator is Updated: Some for the integrated emulators in the Android Emulator may not support the given architecture if the emulator is older. Check if the Android Emulator and Android Studio have the latest versions installed.


If still issues are encountered even after trying these steps, it could be that the specific feature set or hardware that the android application package needs and is unavailable on the emulator; hence, testing on real devices will be the best possible option.
